# Is there any grammatical mistake with the words "an unique beauty"?

Tags: articles

Is it wrong to say "an unique beauty"?
If I name a painting as "an unique beauty", would it be wrong or is there no need to mention both "unique" and "an"?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+unique%2C+a+unique&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20unique%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20unique%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 5):

The word beauty means the quality of being beautiful.  It also means someone or something that is beautiful.

In the former sense, it's an uncountable noun. In the latter, it's a countable noun that can take an indefinite article.

You can say "a unique beauty", not an unique beauty because the letter "u" in the unique gives the sound of a consonant, not the sound of a vowel.

Answer (score 4):

You asked:"**Is it wrong to say 'an unique beauty'?**"

My view on it: yes, it's wrong to say, because *beauty* is a noun and it could be used (it depends on the situation) as a countable or an uncountable noun in English. Let me give you some examples, and I hope those examples will help you.

> An example as the countable noun
>
> 1-She was a great beauty.
>
> An example as the uncountable noun
>
> 1-I am impressed by her beauty.

Now *unique* is an adjective in English and adjectives modify nouns. It's perfectly fine till now, but there is also an article *an* in your statement.

In English we can define the articles into two parts: definite and indefinite articles.  The definite article is *the* and indefinite articles are *a* and *an*. The article *a* comes before a consonant sound and letter (b, c, d etc.) and the article *an* comes before a vowel sound and letter (a, e, i, o, u).

Let me go back to your statement. And as we can see in your statement you used the article *an* before the adjective *unique* but please remember "**English is a language of exceptions**" the adjective *unique* starts with the vowel *u* but it sounds as a consonant, so that's why we have to use the article *a* before the adjective.

So it should have been "a unique beauty".

There are so many other exceptions in the language, for example: an honest boy etc.

I hope it will help you!